# wire:model on file input always send null on hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting, laravel-livewire

I'm quite confused for now, because the wire:model on livewire can't read values from input type files. The results obtained are always null on hosting. I ask everyone for help. Here's the code I use

**Livewire Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Helpers\Logs;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Imports\Admin\Payslip;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ImportPayslip extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $filePayslip;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.payslip.import');
    }

    public function importData()
    {
        $ext = null;
        if(in_array($this->filePayslip->getClientOriginalExtension(),['xlsx','xlsm','xlsb','xltx','xltm','xls','xlt','xml','xlam','xla','xlw','xlr'])){
            $ext = \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX;
        }else{
            $ext = \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV;
        }

        ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','/var/www/html/new-myheart/storage');
        $payslip = new Payslip();
        $payslip->queue($this->filePayslip,null,$ext);
        if($payslip->failures()->isNotEmpty()){
            return redirect()->back()->withFailures($payslip->failures());
        }
        Logs::createLog(Auth::id(), "Import Payslip");
        session()->flash('success','Import Successful');
    }
}
```

**Blade Component**

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">Import Payslip</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="importData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02" wire:model="filePayslip">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="input-group-text btn-primary text-white" type="submit">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

it's all mycode, please i need help

Comment: Why are you doing stuff like `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir')`? (Your storage directory probably shouldn't be your temporary directory. If you want to put stuff there, use the `store` function as documented at https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#storing-files) I'd start simple; use `dd()` to dump out `$this->filePayslip` and make sure it's present first.

Comment: cause i need to set my temp dir

Comment: You shouldn't need to, and if you do, putting all the temporary files in `storage` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: i've done to dd() but return always null on server